# Backend Not receiving Data from the xhr request

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I am using an express server and want to send data from frontend to it using a XMLHttpRequest.
The backend looks like this

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// To parse json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('This is a post request')
    console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

and the frontend looks like this

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataObject))
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataObject))
    xhr.onload = function(){
        alert(xhr.response);
    }
}
```

i get empty brace output on the express console.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

A simple change should make your request work, you need to set the [content-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header on your request so the JSON parser is activated on the server, just one line!

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
```

And your client code now looks something like:

```
let dataObject = { "foo": "bar" };
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataObject))
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/");
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataObject))
xhr.onload = function(){
    alert(xhr.response);
}
```